# after loading InterstitialAd.load with InterstitialAdLoadCallback I have a memory leak

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I call the finish() function in Activity which uses the InterstitialAd announcements but the garbage collector does not recover the activity because call back from InterstitialAd is currently using the activity.
I have a memory leak on all the Activities that call loading InterstitialAd.load with InterstitialAdLoadCallback

how can I use InterstitialAd with InterstitialAdLoadCallback and avoid memory leaks?